# Adding a svg line between 2 divs in flex box

Tags: html, css, reactjs

```
<div class='parent'>
 <div class='Hi'>
   Hi there this is A
 </div>
 <div class='apple'>
   Hi A
  </div>
</div>



.parent{
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
```

I have a parent div and 2 divs inside it. I want to connect space between both these divs with an svg line since the text in both these divs can be variable how do I calculate the length of the space between.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

I used `border`, not `svg`.
The line has full-width of space between, because `flex-grow: 1` and `flex-shrink: 1`.

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.line {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
 <div class='Hi'>
   Hi there this is A
 </div>
 <div class="line"></div>
 <div class='apple'>
   Hi A
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: centered]

As you can see, it's now centered.

Comment: But how do I center this border for that height?

Comment: So you mean not 2px and same height with contents?

Comment: Yes. Basically the centre of the the text vertically should align with the line. Something like -> 

Hi there ---- Hi.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, but this is centered.

Comment: Would you tell me how did you solve it?

Comment: My align-items was commented out. That's why the border was coming at the top for me.